# How to redirect a directory path to a single file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

https://example.com/folder/ needs to direct to https://example.com/folder.html

I added this to the htaccess,

```
Redirect 301 /folder https://example.com/folder.html
```

This works if the url is https://example.com/folder

However if the url is https://example.com/folder/ then it redirects to a broken url at https://example.com/folder.html/

How would I fix this so that https://example.com/folder/ redirects to https://example.com/folder.html/  without the trailing slash causing it to break?

Comment: Does the folder `/folder/` exists in that webroot? And if so, does it contain a `.htaccess` file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use a `RedirectMatch` rule that supports regex with more powerful matching options:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/?$ /folder.html
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or clear browser cache before testing.